# Reading a sql file (database dump) into MATLAB

Tags: mysql, database, matlab, driver

I have a .sql file (named dbdump.sql) in my current MATLAB directory, and I want to get some data out of it into MATLAB. I believe this should be a straightforward task, and here is what I have so far:

```
javaaddpath('C:/mysql-connector-java-5.0.8/mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar') 
con   =  database('dataarchivetest','', '','com.mysql.jdbc.Driver','./dbdump.sql');
query =  exec(con,'select * from test');
```

However, when I inspect the con variable, it gives the following message:

```
'JDBC Driver Error: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver. Driver Not Found/Loaded.'
```

I also tried the following:

```
con   =  database('dataarchivetest','', '','C:/mysql-connector-java-5.0.8/mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar','./dbdump.sql');
query =  exec(con,'select * from test');
```

And got a similar message:

```
JDBC Driver Error: C:/mysql-connector-java-5.0.8/mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar. Driver Not Found/Loaded.
```

I downloaded the MySQL connector from here: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mirror.php?id=13597http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mirror.php?id=13597

I feel I am missing something very simple. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: It won't help you now. But, if you request datadumps in the future and don't want to import them in an sql server, I would recommend requesting a format that you can handle with your existing software.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The connector connects with an SQL server, not with an SQL file. You should set up a SQL server like PostgreSQL or MySQL (for instance on your localhost) and process queries to it.

Comment: Is there any way to read an sql file without importing it into a database and then connecting to it?

Comment: Not as far as I know :(.

Comment: Hey, I imported the sql dump into a database and am trying to connect to it, but I keep getting the driver error even though it seems I am doing everything correct, or no?

Comment: Can you provide some code (how did you setup the database and made the connection)?

Comment: I used the same code as above, but with the following:
con = database('fintest','sjb2_finusr', 'pass','com.mysql.jdbc.Driver','web312.webfaction.com:3306/fintest'); where fintest is the database name on a server I have with webfaction.

Comment: I got the same message: 'JDBC Driver Error: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver. Driver Not Found/Loaded.' I believe it is a driver issue, but I am adding the driver file to the java path, so I am not sure what is wrong.

Comment: Did you install the Java MySQL JDBC library?